# Javascript - clearInterval not working when multiple setInterval

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clearinterval

I got some problem with setInterval & clearInterval.
In my code, I set multiple intervals, and when count reduce to 0, stop the execution.

Like below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0" charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            for (var i=0; i<4; i++){
                var count = 100;

                var IntervalID = window.setInterval((function(){ // closure
                    var timeoutID = IntervalID; // temp
                    var countTemp = count; // temp
                    var id = i;

                    return function(){
                        countTemp --;
                        console.log(id + " " + countTemp);

                        // do something here

                        if ( countTemp == 0 ){                                  
                            clearInterval(timeoutID); // stop the execution
                            console.log(id + " stop");
                        }
                    }
                })(), 20);
            }   
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

After the console appear the stop message "x stop", all element stop except the last element(id:3), it still going.

I try to write my code in another form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0" charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            for (var i=0; i<4; i++){
                doSomething(i);
            }

            function doSomething(id){
                var count = 100;

                var IntervalID = window.setInterval((function(){ // closure
                    var timeoutID = IntervalID; // temp
                    var countTemp = count; // temp

                    return function(){
                        countTemp --;
                        console.log(id + " " + countTemp);

                        // do something here

                        if ( countTemp == 0 ){                                  
                            clearInterval(timeoutID); // stop the execution
                            console.log(id + " stop");
                        }
                    }
                })(), 20);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

But this time, all elements don't stop.

I have two questions:
1. What is difference between these two code?
2. How to make the code work fine?

**Edit:**
If you just want to make the code work, only change one line in the second snippet:

```
clearInterval(timeoutID); // stop the execution
```

to

```
clearInterval(IntervalID); // stop the execution
```

But other people's answer can solve what I confuse at this problem.

Comment: What is IntervalID-s value at the time you trying to use it? Console.log that one out, just below the var timeoutID = IntervalID;

Comment: In the first snippet, the `timeoutID` is undefined for `i==0`, since the call to setInterval hasn't completed yet. Thus, adding `console.log(i + " - " + IntervalID);` immediately above `var timeoutID = IntervalID; // temp` will show you `0 - undefined`, then `1 - 1`, `2 - 2`, `3 - 3`

Comment: Oh, I understand some part, in the first snippet, when `countTemp` reduce to 0, `clearInterval(timeoutID);` actually stop previous one (in `id==1` section, it stop `id==0` execute; `id==2` stop `id==1`; etc. But no one stop `id==3`, so it still going).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the correct **IntervalID** is not being captured in your closure, by the time your closure runs, window.setInterval hasn't returned the id as the assignment expression has not finished yet.

A simple trick can be used with an object, since they are passed to functions by reference in JavaScript

I have modified the loop to accomplish this

```
for (var i=0; i < 4; i++){

    var count = 100;

    var args = { id: i, counter: count };
    var IntervalID = window.setInterval((function(args){ // closure

        return function(){
            args.counter--;
            console.log(args.id + " " + args.counter)
            if ( args.counter == 0 ){                                  
                clearInterval(args.IntervalID); // stop the execution
                console.log(args.id + " stop");
            }
        }.bind(args);
    })(args), 20);

    // by now the correct IntervalID will be captured
    // as the assignment expression has finished executing
    args.IntervalID = IntervalID; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, now I understand more clearly. 
Answer my own question 1, in the first snippet, `timeoutID` capture previous `IntervalID` that remain in memory, so only last one can't stop.
In the second snippet, call one function and pop from founction stack after it finish, so `timeoutID` can't capture any value, it is `undefined`, all elements/intervalIs can't stop.